# Please decipher this C# expression for me

Tags: c#

What does this mean??

```
var cdParams = (includeUniversals) 
? new[] {pageDictionary[pageName], pageDictionary[CNNService.UniversalPage.Name]}
: new[] {pageDictionary[pageName]};
```

Basically it boils down to what does ? mean and what does new[] mean?

Comment: Which part of the expression are you having trouble with? the `?` operator? The `new[]` operator?

Comment: depending on includeUniversals your cdParam is either array of two values or array with only one value of whatever type you have as value in pageDictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cdParams // type inferred by the compiler
 = (includeUniversals) ? // if includeUniversals is true

// then cdParams = new a new array with 2 values coming from a dictionary
 new[] { pageDictionary[pageName], pageDictionary[CNNService.UniversalPage.Name] }

// otherwise, cdParams = a new array with one value
: new[] { pageDictionary[pageName] };
```

See [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [implicit array typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

It's roughly equivalent to this:

```
Foo[] cdParams;  // Use the correct type instead of Foo. NB: var won't work here.
if (includeUniversals) { 
    dParams = new Foo[2];
    dParams[0] = pageDictionary[pageName];
    dParams[1] = pageDictionary[CNNService.UniversalPage.Name];
} else {
    dParams = new Foo[1];
    dParams[0] = pageDictionary[pageName];
}
```

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr.: `new[]` means that it infers the type. It might not be `object`, but some other type. I've updated the code to make it more explicit.

Comment: Guess I never noticed that, and my usage always resulted in object[]. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the question again, Foo is probably Page. Whatever that is.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [ternary expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  If the condition is true, then execute the first case.  If it is false, then execute the second case.

Answer (score 3):

If the boolean `includeUniversals` evaluates to true then return a new anonymous object array containing `pageDictionary[pageName]` and `pageDictionary[CNNService.UniversalPage.Name]` otherwise return a new anonymous object array containing `pageDictionary[pageName]`

That what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on `includeUniversals`, `cdParams` will be an array with two values in it, namely `pageDictionary[pageName]` and `pageDictionary[CNNService.UniversalPage.Name]` - OR, it will be an array with one value in it, namely `pageDictionary[pageName]`.