# What is the difference between new[] and new string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this new[] a shorthand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056311/what-is-this-new-a-shorthand-for)

Is there any difference between

```
var strings = new string[] { "hello", "world" };
```

and

```
var strings2 = new[] { "hello", "world" };
```

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with this being "too localised". While it's not an *advanced* question, it's definitely something that quite a lot of people encounter. =)

Comment: I neither agree with the downvote nor with it being "too localised". It's a valid question, many junior (and definitely some not-so-junior) developers probably don't know this. To have this here as a future reference will really be helpful for many to come.

Comment: This is a fine question, but closing as a duplicate. I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558891/453277) a variation of this question myself.

Comment: I'd argue a variation is not the same as a duplicate, especially when one question asks for the meaning of the syntax and one asks for the difference between 2 syntaxes (syntaxi?), but it's only a minor quibble. It's already been answered anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this case, no difference, as `new[]` will infer the provided values type as `string`.

See [Implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx).

Comment: totally correct c# is very variable with the type definition, however I would always implicitly define the variable type to avoid casting error, respectively to directly see errors, which can appear while casting

Comment: @Nickolaus: There is no casting here. That variable is still strongly typed.

Comment: @Nickolaus Nor is there any casting with the `var` keyword, which is what I suspect you're implying. =)

Comment: yeah, sorry,... missed that var is a dynamic type... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: @Nickolaus Whether you use `var` or explicitly declared types is just a matter of taste and level of needed clarity, really. ^^

Comment: @Nickolaus You shouldn't really say dynamic when referring to `var`. `var` is actually strongly-typed, unlike C#'s `dynamic`.

Answer (score 7):

No difference.

The second one is a syntactic-sugar called ["Implicitly typed arrays"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx), and both the expressions return an array of strings.

When you don't specify the type of the array, it is *inferred* from the types of the elements used to initialize the array.
To allow the inference, the expression must satisfy the following condition:

*Considering an implicitly typed array expression like this:*

```
   var arr = new []{ obj1, ... , objn }
```

*and the set of all the types of the elements in the initialization being:*

```
   S = {T1, ..., Tn}
```

*to allow the inference (i.e. no compiler error) it must be possible for all the types* `{ T1, ... , Tn }` *to be implicitly cast to one of the types in the set* `S`.

So, for example, given the following classes:

```
class Base { }
class Derived1 : Base { }
class Derived2 : Base { }
class Derived3
{ 
    public static implicit operator Base(Derived3 m)
    { return null; }
}
```

This code compiles:

```
var arr = new []{ new Derived1(), new Derived2(), new Derived3(), new Base()};
```

while the following does not:

```
var arr = new []{ new Derived1(), new Derived2(), new Derived3() };
```

since in the first case all the 3 types can be implicitly cast to type `Base`, and `Base` type is inside the set `S = { Derived1, Derived2, Derived3, Base }`, while in the second case all the types cannot be cast to one type in the set `S = { Derived1, Derived2, Derived3 }`

---

This feature has been introduced with C# 3.0 along with anonymous types and it makes instantiation of arrays of the latter easier.

For instance, this would be really hard to obtain without implicitly typed arrays:

```
var arrayOfAnonymous = new[] { new { A = 3, B = 4 }, new { A = 2, B = 5 } };
```

Comment: Any idea which version of C# introduced this?

Comment: It was introduced in C# 3.0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic16

Comment: @CalebJares: Elaborated a bit...

Answer (score 6):

In this case, ***there is no difference***. Because of `hello` and `world` are `string`;

```
var strings2 = new[] { "hello", "world" };
```

creates a `string[]` array which is the same with first one.

[image]

Second one is just called *[`Implicitly Typed Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)*

If we go one step further, they have the same `IL` code.

Comment: I prefer linqpad for this kind of visualisation, personally. Still. Very clear, that. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I always prefer Linqpad but it has a debugging mode? If it has, I miss it since for a loooong time =)

Comment: Ah, no, no debugging mode - but I just `.Dump()` everything to output, as I need it. =)

Comment: But this visualisation needs debugging mode ;)

Comment: Personally, I found the concise output of the results window in linqpad (e.g. `new[]{"hi","bye"}.Dump();`) to be satisfactory. But, taste is always very subjective. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Oh, now I see your point. Yes you are right Linqpad visualisation is much more easier and looks more efficient.

Comment: Like I said, taste is subjective. Glad I could show you my opinion!

Answer (score 2):

None, the compile interprets it as `new string[] { "hello", "world" };`

It's just like using `var`, the compiler handles what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

new[] creates an [implicitly typed array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) in which the type is infered from the elements. while the other approach creates an array of string.

Comment: yup, i expressed myself wrongly, it's not an array of objects it's just inferring the type from the elements with which it;s initialized

Comment: Well, that's something *entirely* different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.
In the 2nd case, the C# compiler is smart enough to infer the type of the array, since it sees that the values that are used to initialize the array, are of type string.